# how to get position from programmatically created spinners

Tags: android, spinner

when the user enters a number in a edittext my app then creates and displays that many spinners. The user will then select an item from each spinner and then click a save button. I have looked on the internet but have been unable to find a way to retrieve the position from the spinners. Here is how I created the spinners:

```
//numStockTanks is the number of spinners to be created
numStockTanks = Integer.parseInt(numOfStockTanks.getText().toString());             
    // creates all the fields
    for(int i = 1; i <= numStockTanks; i++) {
        TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);
        // creates the textView
        tV1 = new TextView(this);
        tV1.setText("Stock Tank #" + i + " size: ");

        // add spinner to row
        spinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterStockTankSize2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.StockTankSize, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterStockTankSize2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterStockTankSize2);
        spinner.setId(1000 + i);

        // add the TextView and the editText to the new TableRow
        tR.addView(tV1);
        tR.addView(spinner);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tL.addView(tR,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    
    } // end for statement
} // end getNumberCreateSpinner ()
```

I have attemped several different way to get the position of the spinners but I cant seem to figure it out. Here is what I currently have:

```
ArrayList<Integer> mArraySpinner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < numStockTanks; i++) {
           spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(1000 + i);
           if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
               mArraySpinner.add(100);
           } else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2) {
               mArraySpinner.add(200);
           } else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
               mArraySpinner.add(210);
          } else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4) {
               mArraySpinner.add(295);
           } else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 5) {
               mArraySpinner.add(400);
          } else mArraySpinner.add(0);
    } // end for statement
```

Thanks for your help

Edit:
Updated to my latest attempt after the first answer

Edit Edit:
When I debug the line "spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(1000 + i);" it says null so I know that I am not pointing to my spinner correctely this is what I need the help with

Edit: bump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set an `onItemSelectedListener` when you create the spinner (inside the loop where you create the spinner), and use that to set the value into an array that is a class field.

```
mArraySpinner = new Array<Integer>[numStockTanks];
for(int i = 1; i <= numStockTanks; i++) { 

      // code to set spinner adapter, etc.

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
       mArraySpinner[i] = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont think I need a listener because I am retrieving the position on a click event not after the spinners are being changed.

Comment: Just use the listener to set the array value (you'd have to create the array with the spinners instead of later), and then the button to finalize/act upon it.  Updated my answer to flesh it/show my thinking.

Comment: i tried to use this code, the problem i am finding with it is that the listener is "fired" in the onCreate method an thus a value of 0 is entered into the array

Comment: Yeah, that means they haven't made a selection.  When they make a selection, the entry will be changed. You could also put a counter in the listener and increment it each time.  If the counter equals 0 you don't do anything but increment the counter.  If the counter is > 0 (indicating that a selection has been made after the initial spinner set) then you update the array.  Note that the code you posted is returning the position in the spinner of the selection, not the contents, so that is what I made my example do as well...

Comment: i am unable to get any positive results from this, even with some variations. any other thoughts?

Comment: After some playing around I did get this to work with your answer and a counter to so that it would not add to my array when the listener is fired, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you are using `1000++` for the spinner id. and while you are trying to get the spinner possing you check it with `100++`.

Please update the if condition which you are written in your code.
change `100` to `1000`

i have changed and put the sample code below from your code.

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(1000 + i);
       if (spinner.getId().equals("1000")) {
           mArraySpinner.add(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
       } 
       else if(....){....}
```

Comment: after your responce I realized an error in my code so I have updated the question